# MySQL query: Single Table multiple comparisions

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql table:

```
id     |  member     |
1      | abc       
1      | pqr   
2      | xyz   
3      | pqr   
3      | abc
```

I have been trying to write a query which would return the id which has exact same members as a given id. For example, if given id is 1 then the query should return 3 because both id 1 and id 3 have exact same members viz. {abc, pqr}. Any pointers? Appreciate it.

**EDIT:** The table may have duplicates, e.g. id 3 may have members {abc, abc} instead of {pqr, abc}, in which case the query should not return id 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similar (to Derek Kromm's) approach using sub-queries:

```
SELECT id
FROM mc a
WHERE
  id != 1 AND
  member IN (
    SELECT member FROM mc WHERE id=1)
GROUP BY id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) IN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mc WHERE id=1) AND
  COUNT(*) IN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mc where id=a.id);
```

a logic here is we need all ids that match following 2 conditions:

- member is among those that belong to id 1
- total number of members is same as number of those that belong to id 1
- total number of selected members equal to total number of members for current id

Comment: Thanks..works perfectly...as long as there are no duplicates. i.e. if id 3 had members {abc, abc} instead of {abc, pqr}, then this query would still return 3 which would be wrong because id 1 & id 3 don't have exact same members in that case. Can the query be modified to take care of this situation (duplicates)?

Comment: okay. The only modification to the above query is to replace COUNT(*) by COUNT(DISTINCT member) in the last line so that it takes care of the duplicates case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that finds matching pairs for the entire table - you can add a where clause to filter as needed. Basically it does a self-join based on equal "member" and unequal "id". It then compares the resulting count grouped by the 2 ids and compares them to the total count of those ids from the original table. If they both match, it means they have the same exact members.

```
select
    t1.id, t2.id
from
    table t1
    inner join table t2
        on  t1.member = t2.member
            and t1.id < t2.id
    inner join (select id, count(1) as cnt from table group by id) c1
        on  t1.id = c1.id
    inner join (select id, count(1) as cnt from table group by id) c2
        on  t2.id = c2.id
group by
    t1.id, t2.id, c1.cnt, c2.cnt
having
    count(1) = c1.cnt
    and count(1) = c2.cnt
order by 
    t1.id, t2.id
```

This is some sample data I used which returned matches of (1,3) and (6,7)

```
insert into table
values 
    (1, 'abc'), (1, 'pqr'), (2, 'xyz'), (3, 'pqr'), (3, 'abc'), (4, 'abc'), (5, 'pqr'),
    (6, 'abc'), (6, 'def'), (6, 'ghi'), (7, 'abc'), (7, 'def'), (7, 'ghi')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see the logic seems correct but what is table t2?

Comment: wherever you see "table", just plugin your tablename. t1 and t2 are just table aliases so that you can reference the same table more than once in a query

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @id int
set @id=1
select a.id from
(select id,COUNT(*) cnt from sample_table
where member in (select member from sample_table where id=@id)
and id <>@id
group by id)a
join
(select count(distinct member) cnt from sample_table where id=@id)b
on a.cnt=b.cnt
```